# largeTitleDisplayMode doesn't work properly?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, preferslargetitles

I added the `UINavigationBar` with a large title in it. After that, I added a `UITableView` to this `UIViewController`. I gave the large title content mode to `.always`. But when I scroll the `UITableView it hides and showed in the top of the`UINavigationBar`

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
self.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always
```

Comment: Setting `largeTitleDisplayMode` doesn't change what happens when you _scroll_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to keep your large title while scrolling your **UITableView**, then add a **UIView** on top of your **UITableView**, like:

[image]